# Proxy in between device and Google IoT Core using MQTT?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mqtt, iot, google-cloud-iot

I have a situation where I want to use Google IoT Core to support bi-directional communication between my devices and existing GCP stack. The trouble is, some of my devices cannot connect to GCP's MQTT bridge because they are blocked from reaching it directly. The communication must instead go through my own hosted server. In fact, some devices will not be allowed to trust traffic either inbound or outbound to anything but my own hosted server, and this is completely out of my control.

Basically all suggested solutions that I have found propose the use of MQTT over WebSockets. WebSockets consume too many system resources for the server I have available, and so MQTT proxy over WebSockets is extremely undesirable and likely is not even feasible for my use case. It also defeats the purpose of using a lightweight, low-bandwidth protocol like MQTT in the first place.

To make matters more complicated, Google IoT Core documentation explicitly says that it does not support bridging MQTT brokers with their MQTT bridge. So hosting my own MQTT server seems to be out of the question.

Is it even possible to create a proxy -- either forward or reverse -- for this use case that allows for native, encrypted, full-duplex MQTT traffic? If so, what would be the recommended way to achieve this?

Comment: have you tried checking this guide on how to setup MQTT https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge#mqtt_server or this Github post that you use MQTT Cloud Pub/Sub Proxy set-up https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-pubsub-mqtt-proxy.

Comment: @BryanL yes, I've checked out much of the GCP documentation looking for an answer. The github repo you've linked is unfortunately not a viable option. This project has the constraint that it has to go through my server first because some clients will only be configured to trust traffic between my servers and the device. Any traffic to Google servers is not permitted.

EDIT: I have changed the question to better communicate the constraints.

Comment: If my understanding is correct based on your statements. I assume your current set up is hybrid, you have on-premise servers (your own hosted server) and a cloud server (existing GCP stack) you want to bridge them using Google IoT by using MQTT. You can try in this github link, upon checking this MQTT broker has been tested to Google IoT, https://github.com/nhonchu/mqttClient-for-Legato

Comment: @BryanL thank you for your recommendation. I will look into this as I explore my options.

Answer (score 0):

If you have hybrid set-up, meaning you have on-premise servers and a cloud server and you want to bridge them using Google IoT by using MQTT.

You can try in this github link, upon checking this [MQTT broker](https://github.com/nhonchu/mqttClient-for-Legato) has been tested to Google IoT. Since Google IoT is not supporting 3rd paryt MQTT broker.